# Issue getting user by id

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am having issues with discord.js and using id's to get a user in a guild. I have used two different methods of getting users in a guild:
`message.guild.members.cache.get(id)` and `client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id).members.cache.get(id)`. Both get a list of users, however they only give me the bot and myself. All other users are undefined. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to fetch the users in a guild ( cached ) so you may do

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach((x) => { console.log(x.user.id) });
// or alternatively 
client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id).members.cache.forEach((x) => { console.log(x.user.id) });
```

This would loop through the whole collection of cached users and log the IDs of whole member list in your console.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I have the id, I need the user info. I don't want to fetch all users, only the one specified. Additionally, the contents of the members cache is me and the bot.

Comment: then you may use 
```
message.guild.members.fetch(id).then( member => console.log(member))
```

Comment: Kind of similar in topic and the reason I didn't want to use promises, how can I carry a variable outside of the .then?

Comment: You may declare it outside and the use it like:. let x; message.guild.members.fetch(Id).then( member => x = member); console.log(x) // you have it outside then :)

Comment: Could you please look at this pastebin and tell me what I'm doing wrong? [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fBjPnjRF).

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're only searching the cache for the user you're looking for. The cache will only contain users that the bot has seen since it started (it's more complicated than that but that's an easy way to think about it). Try fetching the user using the following instead:

```
message.guild.members.fetch(id);
```

Please note that this function returns a `Promise` though so you will need to either use `.then()` or `await` (provided you're in an `async` function) to wait until it has fetched the user from the API.